# Has an invalid foreign key Django TestCase

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-tests

i have a model pruchase and a model transaction, transactions have a ForeignKey from pruchase and when a try run the tests success th first test_payment_request but the second test_payment_transaction_state faile an launch the next error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'transactions_transactionmodel' with primary key '0664aefce71447699d8ca9e7677ba4cc' has an invalid foreign key: transactions_transactionmodel.purchase_id contains a value 'ba7dc5ac0e1c4b9eb009e772f405f5db' that does not have a corresponding value in purchases_purchasemodel.id.
```

this is my test:

```
import datetime
import socket
from django.test import TestCase
from .payment import PaymentTransactions
from apps.purchases.models import PurchaseModel

class PaymentTransactionsTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.purchase = {"purchase":PurchaseModel( total_value = 124236,
                                                   products = [
                                                                {
                                                                    "name": "Aretes",
                                                                    "value": "6490"
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                    "name": "Manilla",
                                                                    "value": "6.000"
                                                                }
                                                            ],
                                                    purchase_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                                                 ),
                         "value":124236,
                         "client_ip": socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
                        }

    def test_payment_request(self):
        error, payment, transaction = PaymentTransactions().\
                                      payment_transaction_request(**self.purchase)
        self.assertFalse(error)
        self.assertTrue(payment)
        self.assertIn("tpaga_payment_url", payment)
        self.assertIn("token", payment)
        self.assertEquals(transaction.token, payment["token"])
        print("paso prueba 1")

    def test_payment_transaction_state(self):
        purchase = {"purchase":PurchaseModel( total_value = 124236,
                                                   products = [
                                                                {
                                                                    "name": "Aretes",
                                                                    "value": "6490"
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                    "name": "Manilla",
                                                                    "value": "6.000"
                                                                }
                                                            ],
                                                    purchase_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                                                 ),
                         "value":124236,
                         "client_ip": socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
                        }
        error, payment, transaction = PaymentTransactions().\
                                      payment_transaction_request(**purchase)
        self.assertFalse(error)
        error, transaction_created =  PaymentTransactions().\
                                       payment_transaction_state(transaction.id)
        self.assertFalse(error)
        self.assertEquals(transaction_created.state, transaction.state)
```

but i don't know whatshappends if someone know, please can explain me.

Comment: You have to save `PurchaseModel` first before assigning to transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Make change models.`SOMETHING` to models.CASCADE in your field of Model `Payment`.